# Angularjs access last entity of a $resource from controller

Tags: angularjs

How do I get the at the last entity of a rest resource from within the controller?

I have a factory that restuens a $resource:

```
angular.module('foo', ['ngResource']).
factory('Api', ['$resource',
   function($resource) {
    return {
        Bars: $resource('url/.../', {})
        .
        .
        //other resources
        .
        };
}]);
```

I would like to remove the last elemet this resource returns, but I do not know how to reference this element e.g.

```
function barControl($scope, $http, Api) {
   Api.Bar.remove(Api.Bar[lastIdx], [success], [failure]);
   $scope.bar = Api.Bars.query();
  ....
   //do stuff
```

How do I make the Api.Bar.lastIdx statement?

thank youin advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `Api.Bars.query()` call return an array, you should be able to simple do:

```
var lastItem = $scope.bar.pop()
```

Here is more info about `.pop()` method:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop